# ¿Como redirigir red local a ip o dominio especifico?

Tags: http, dns, router, wifi

Me pregunto como puedo hacer para que cualquiera que se una a una red local, LAN o WLAN, sea enviado a una ip especifica, sin importar que dirección coloque.

Porque deseo montar un servidor en una red local para un único propósito, sin la dificulta de explicarle a nadie que debe ingresar a una IP. Solo se conecta y es redirigido.

He leido temas similares, pero nada exactamente a lo que busco. He leido sobre NAT, y tambien que quizas se haga con un DNS local.

¿Que debo configurar para que pueda hacerlo con un router TP-Link o uno cualquiera? ¿Es necesario instalar DD-WRT o OpenWRT?

Ejemplo por si no me explico.

Fulano se conecta a un WiFi llamado `Biblioteca`, y al entrar en el navegador es redirigido a `http://192.168.1.100/` o `http://biblioteca.lan/` donde podra navegar en mi servidor.

Nadie le dijo que debía ingresar a `192.168.1.100` o `biblioteca.lan`